# Simple geofences not working

Tags: java, android, gps, location, android-geofence

I'm trying to implement simple Android application that allows user to save locations and show reminder when user is near to specific location. However my geofences don't seem to trigger. I have spent some time with this but have been unable to find solution.

App should work like this:
1. go to location
2. add location reminder
3. get reminder when you are near the location

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {

final static int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 0;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location mLocation;

private double lat, lng;
private float radius=1000;
String ACTION_FILTER = "com.example.mikes.locationreminder";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    registerReceiver(new Geofences(), new IntentFilter(ACTION_FILTER));

    locationManager=(LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    Intent i= new Intent(ACTION_FILTER);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), -1, i, 0);

    locationManager.addProximityAlert(mLocation.getLatitude(), mLocation.getLongitude(), radius, -1, pi);


}
....
```

Geofences:

```
public class Geofences extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

    boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if(state){
        Log.i("MyTag", "In secret area");
        Toast.makeText(context, "In secret area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        Log.i("MyTag", "Left secret area");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Left secret area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If it's indeed "simple", what's with all this extra code?

Comment: I edited to make code simpler